# EF 6 Include Issue before selecting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Hello I am creating query thats should return Candidates that have ReqruitmenStage with Stage 0.

My edmx: [image]
And this is my code:

```
  db.RecruitmentStages.Include("Candidate")
                        .Include("Candidate.Person")
                        .Include("Candidate.Document")
                        .Include("Candidate.Decision")
                        .Include("Candidate.Evaluation")
                        .Include("Candidate.Evaluation.SkillsEvaluation")
                        .Include("Candidate.Evaluation.SkillsEvaluation.Skill")
                        .Include("Candidate.Evaluation.SoftSkillsEvaluation")
                        .Include("Candidate.Evaluation.SoftSkillsEvaluation.SoftSkill")
                        .Where(x => x.Stage == 0)
                        .Select(y => y.Candidate)
```

After loading data, my collection should have 1 item, and it works, but instance of Person is null.

I checked simplier version to prove that: there is no database errors in tables.

```
db.Candidates.Include("Person")
                    .Include("Document")
                    .Include("Decision")
                    .Include("RecruitmentStage")
                    .Include("Evaluation")
                    .Include("Evaluation.SkillsEvaluation")
                    .Include("Evaluation.SkillsEvaluation.Skill")
                    .Include("Evaluation.SoftSkillsEvaluation")
                    .Include("Evaluation.SoftSkillsEvaluation.SoftSkill")
```

In this case Person has value.

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe in the db there is no matching record of `Person` ?

Comment: There is matching record of Person. I checked it several times =)